# How can i do animations to show item CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, sass, css-animations

am looking for a solution to make some animations on an item when we try to load the next one.
Here is what i have:

**Before i click i have this :**
[image]

**After Click:**
[image]

I want to show the image in background when i click on the list element at the right side (Man, Woman...).
The backgroud image is hidden on the right, it exceeds the screen and this one is resized.

I need to hide the backgroundimage without resizing the screen, and show it when click with animation.

CSS:

```
    img.slider__bg {
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        transform: translateX(100%);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
        transition: transform .5s 4s;
    
        &.showBg {
          animation: showBg 0.5s forwards;
          -webkit-animation: showBg 0.5s forwards;
        }
     
        &.hideBg {
            animation: hideBg 0.5s forwards;
            -webkit-animation: hideBg 0.5s forwards;
        }
     @keyframes showBg {
        100% { transform: translateX(0%); }
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes showBg {
        100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(0%); }
    }
        
    @keyframes hideBg {
        0% { transform: translateX(0%); }
        100% { transform: translateX(100%); }
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes hideBg {
        0% { -webkit-transform: translateX(0%); }
        100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `conditional rendering` to display the background image when you click. You need to `declare a state` to identify whether you clicked or not.